# Is there anything similar to "#pragma GCC system_header" for MSVS?

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-warnings, pragma

We try to enable as many warnings as possible in our project, and warnings are promoted to errors. We disable useless warnings or ones that are too fuzzy.

Recently I added a third party single-header library in our project. It has a few warnings, which we don't want to disable or fix in this file.

I found that GCC has `#pragma GCC system_header`, which treats current file as a system file (by using `-isystem` instead of `-I`), and this disables all warnings from this file.

The questions is - is there anything similar to this pragma in Visual Studio?

Comment: No, nothing like that.  Do favor isolating such code in its own translation unit.  But if necessary just write your own .h file that #includes the wonky one.  Wrapped with #pragma warning push/pop to temporarily suppress the warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution I used to disable warnings from a third party header:

```
#pragma warning(push, 0)
#include <...>
#pragma warning(pop)
```